# How to combine default and named exports into one statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two exports:

```
export { round, getCompassDirection };
export default App;
```

How can I combine them into one call?

I tried:

```
export App, { round, getCompassDirection };
```

and

```
export default App, { round, getCompassDirection };
```

but I get syntax errors. I searched for answers but the subject is broad and I get a lot of results that don't address this specific need.

Answer (score 9):

Using this syntax works:

```
export { App as default, round, getCompassDirection };
```